# How Wifis and wifi security work?

Tags: security, wireless-networking, wep, wpa

I see tons of videos dealing with WEP cracking, but actaully none of them teach about how Wifis work. They are just a bunch of commands thrown at the screen. Where can I learn about the inner mechanics of wifis? Can you recommend a website or a book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- HowStuffWorks: [**How WiFi Works**](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/wireless-network.htm)
- [**6 Steps to Secure Your Home Wireless Network**](http://www.tonybradley.com/2009/07/6-steps-to-secure-your-home-wireless-network/)
- SANS paper: [**How Things Work: WLAN Technologies and Security Mechanisms**](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/wireless/how_things_work_wlan_technologies_and_security_mechanisms_1301) (PDF)
- Nice SecurityFocus article [**Coffee shop WiFi**](http://www.securityfocus.com/columnists/385) (2006)
- [**WarDrive.net**](http://www.wardrive.net/)
- [**Getting deep at SANS**](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/wireless/)
- [Breaking](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/how-to-crack-wep,review-451.html) WEP [Encryption](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers-internet/break-wep-encryption)

  - [**WEP Security Called Unreliable**](http://onekit.net/store/review/wep_security_called_unreliable.html), has a paper reference.

And, [**10 Tips for Wireless Home Network Security**](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wirelesssecurity/tp/wifisecurity.htm)
I skipped the Wikipedia, but you can look it up from these references.

Comment: Any raw in-depth book recommendations for fundamental understanding?

Answer (score 2):

The podcast "Security Now" did a full show about wifi security, you can find the transcript here :

http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-170.htm ([in pdf here](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-170.pdf))

It is very detailed :

> Steve: No. No. And there again, AES is
>   a cipher called "Rijndael." TKIP is a
>   protocol. CCMP is the protocol which
>   uses AES. I mean, so my point is...

Comment: This was a really useful read. Very detailed, but still quite understandable. Steve is really awesome at explaining things. Big thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking in a personal sense, I think there are some great answers already posted.

If you are looking in a professional sense, I would recommend looking into CWNP site (http://www.cwnp.com/), which provides a vendor neutral 802.11 certification path.